# Should I include country dummies when I combine datasets of 3 countries?

Tags: stata, cross-section, controlling-for-a-variable, ordered-probit

I am currently doing the analysis using firm-level data of three countries combining together. Also, it is a cross-sectional analysis. Therefore, in the Ordered Probit regression, I control for industry dummies to account for differential effects in the industry level.

I think I don't need to control for country dummies due to some reasons: (1) The countries that I use in my analysis share similar characteristics including development level, political, and socio-economic conditions. (2) There are only three countries in my analysis.

In this case, I expect that the results will not be affected even though I don't control for country specifics.

However, I am not sure if my idea is appropriate since I cannot find any reference to support it yet. Therefore, I would like to ask everybody here if you have any idea whether or not country dummies is necessary in my case.

Thank you!

Comment: Without knowing the exact context of the model it is hard to give a full answer; But I don't think the examples you give to not include country level variables are very compelling: (1) the key is in the use of *similar*, eg. they're still not identical, and so therefore might have nuanced differences, (2) there are many models that use binary variables (eg. sex in a medical trial) so three countries doesn't seem small. You may wish to fit the model using multi-level/hierarchical modelling if you expect the countries behaviours to be similar.

Comment: @owen88 My objective is to study a causal relation that is independent of country. So, I think that including country dummies will be the right thing to do. However, I got a problem when I include those country variables, that is the parallel assumption for ordered probit regression is violated. So, I am now trying to figure out any possible solution. I would also appreciate it if you have some suggestions, like to run the regression for each country separately or other possible ways